# Editor Font not displaying text properly in PyCharm

Tags: python, fonts, pycharm

I started using PyCharm recently but noticed something strange about the font.  When I use a font that is not a monospace font it is displayed really strangely in PyCharm (see screenshot).  Does anyone know how to fix this?  I have seen non monospace font displayed properly in PyCharm by Derek Banas in his [Python programming tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA) so I know it will work but it isn't working for me.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of text in editor]

If you can't see it that well it looks like there are little white vertical lines through the text.

Comment: Today, I updated on PycharmPro 2017 and I have the same problem.